# Commitment scheme: hiding property

Tags: commitments, hybrid-encryption

Given two commitment schemes $Com_1, Com_2$ (both have the hiding property), I'd like to prove $Com_1(m) || Com_2(m)$ is also hiding.

I built these hybrids and want to show $H_0 =_c H_1 =_c H_2$.

\begin{align}
H_0 &= Com_1(m) || Com_2(m) \\
H_1 &= R_1 || Com_2(m) \\
H_2 &= R_1 || R_2
\end{align}

For $H_1 =_c H_2$: If some $D$ tells apart $H_1$ from $H_2$ then we can distinguish $Com_2(m)$ and $R_2$ by prepending some random $R_1$ and then call $D$.

But how could we prove $H_0 =_c H_1$?

Comment: You should check the definition of hiding. A commitment scheme is not required to be pseudorandom. It can be trivial to distinguish a commitment from a random value, so your hybrids are not indistinguishable. Hiding is about not being able to distinguish between commitments of $m_0$ and $m_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is not homework. It should be almost the same as proving $H_1=_cH_2$. Just let the distinguisher (that distinguishes $Com_1(m)$ and $R_1$) generate and append $Com_2(m)$ in both worlds. This can perfectly simulate the view of the distinguisher that distinguishes $H_0$ and $H_1$.

Comment: (edited) Thanks Shan. This proof is part of a previously completed homework question which I am now reviewing. I previously missed that (1) the hiding property involves two different messages $m_0$ and $m_1$, and (2) the two message are be chosen by the adversary (and therefore adversary can compute $Com_1(m_b)$ and $Com_2(m_b)$ where $b\in \{0,1\}$) because in order to satisfy the hiding property, the commitment scheme must produce computationally indistinguishable ciphers for ALL pairs of messages.

Comment: @sam My pleasure. Btw, I think for the commitment hiding property indistinguishability between two chosen messages can be implied by indistinguishability between one chosen message and a random string (as described in your question).

Answer (score 0):

The hybrids you came up with are not helpful for proving the statement. A commitment scheme is not required to have commitments be indistinguishable from random strings.
For example, let $\operatorname{Com}$ be a (binding and hiding) commitment scheme, then $\operatorname{Com'}$ defined as $$\operatorname{Com'}(m) = 0\|\operatorname{Com}(m)$$
is also hiding and binding. But with $\operatorname{Com'}$ your hybrids are trivially distinguishable with probability $1/2$ by simply checking whether the first bit is zero (or the first bit of the second half for $H_1,H_2$).

The hiding experiment works by letting the adversary choose two messages $m_0,m_1$. The adversary then receives either $\operatorname{Com}(m_0)$ or $\operatorname{Com}(m_1)$ and should not be able to distinguish between the two cases with more than negligible probability.

To then prove the original statement from you question, that $\operatorname{Com}(m) = \operatorname{Com_1}(m)\|\operatorname{Com_2}(m)$ is hiding whenever both $\operatorname{Com_1}$ and $\operatorname{Com_2}$ are hiding you can indeed work with a hybrid argument.

Your extreme hybrids are the two cases of the hiding experiment. I.e., in hybrid $H_0$, the adversary will receive $\operatorname{Com_1}(m_0)\|\operatorname{Com_2}(m_0)$ and in $H_2$, the adversary will receive $\operatorname{Com_1}(m_1)\|\operatorname{Com_2}(m_1)$.
You can then define an intermediate hybrid $H_1$, where the adversary receives $\operatorname{Com_1}(m_1)\|\operatorname{Com_2}(m_0)$ instead.

The reduction to show that each pair of hybrids is indistinguishable is very simple. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an arbitrary PPT distinguisher against the hiding property of $\operatorname{Com}$.

We then construct a distinguisher $\mathcal{R}$ against the hiding property of $\operatorname{Com_1}$ as follows: $\mathcal{R}$ runs $\mathcal{A}$ and receives two messages $m_0,m_1$, that it also outputs to the outer hiding experiment, receiving a commitment $c_1$ as  response. $\mathcal{R}$ then gives $c_1\|\operatorname{Com_2}(m_0)$ to $\mathcal{A}$. Eventually $\mathcal{A}$ outputs a bit $b'$, which $\mathcal{R}$ also outputs. Note that if $\mathcal{R}$ receives $c_1=\operatorname{Com_1}(m_0)$, then it perfectly simulates $H_0$. On the other hand if it receives $c_1=\operatorname{Com_1}(m_1)$, then it perfectly simulates $H_1$. Thus, $\mathcal{R}$ distinguishes those two cases with the same probability with which $\mathcal{A}$ distinguishes $H_0$ and $H_1$. By the assumption that $\operatorname{Com_1}$ is hiding, this implies that the probability must be negligible.

Similarly, we can construct a distinguisher $\mathcal{R}$ against the hiding property of $\operatorname{Com_2}$. $\mathcal{R}$ runs $\mathcal{A}$ and receives two messages $m_0,m_1$, that it also outputs to the outer hiding experiment, receiving a commitment $c_2$ as  response. $\mathcal{R}$ then gives $\operatorname{Com_1}(m_1)\|c_2$ to $\mathcal{A}$. Eventually $\mathcal{A}$ outputs a bit $b'$, which $\mathcal{R}$ also outputs. Note that if $\mathcal{R}$ receives $c_2=\operatorname{Com_1}(m_0)$, then it perfectly simulates $H_1$. On the other hand if it receives $c_2=\operatorname{Com_1}(m_1)$, then it perfectly simulates $H_2$. Thus, $\mathcal{R}$ distinguishes those two cases with the same probability with which $\mathcal{A}$ distinguishes $H_1$ and $H_2$. By the assumption that $\operatorname{Com_2}$ is hiding, this implies that the probability must be negligible.

Using the triangle inequality we can then conclude that also $H_0$ and $H_2$ must be indistinguishable, thus proving hiding of $\operatorname{Com}$.